# YQL returning null results from one client, populated results from another

Tags: yql

I have an application using a YQL query to convert results to jsonp format.

It has been working for several days, but suddenly started returning null results:

```
jsonp1296156548953({"query":{"count":0,"created":"2011-01-27T19:31:04Z","lang":"en-US","results":null}});
```

Oddly, when run from a different IP address it returns the expected results. Client browser is firefox in both cases.

This is a query against http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql which is supposed to have a limit of 1000 queries per hour, this application does about one per minute. But I wonder if this could be an indication of exceeding some kind of limit at a particular IP? Status code of the return is 200 and there is no indication in the response headers that anything is wrong.

Comment: Can you provide the full requests and responses from the working and non-working locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thread at YDN appears to describe this problem.  Apparently it is fixed as of this morning:

http://developer.yahoo.net/forum/?showtopic=8291&endsession=1

Answer (score 1):

yup I'm seeing the same issue. Try going to the console and coping the url for your query into the browser and refershing. You'll see that sometimes the results come up and other times they don't.